# From procedural to OOP date format function

Tags: php

This is a procedural function I made for displaying date. I am trying to convert it to OOP. It's an exercise to learn OOP.  I know it's quite simple but I am just beginning to learn OOP PHP.  Thank you if you can shed a light on this.

```
<?php

function getMonth( $monthNum ){

$listMonth = array( 'janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre' );

return $listMonth[ ( $monthNum - 1 ) ];

}


function getDay( $day ){

if( $day == '01' || $day == '1' ) return '1<sup>er</sup>';
else return $day;

 }
   function dateFormat( $date, $format = 'dd mm YYYY' ){

  list( $year, $month, $day ) = explode( '-', $date );

  switch( $format ){

    case 'dd mm YYYY' : $dateFormat = getDay( $day ).'-'.getMonth( $month ).'-'.$year; break;

    case 'mm YYYY' : $dateFormat = getMonth( $month ).'- '.$year; break;

    default : $dateFormat = getDay( $day ).'- '.getMonth( $month ).'-'.$year; break;

}

return $dateFormat;
 }

 echo dateFormat('14-01-2014');


?>
```

Comment: You are the one wanting to learn so why ask somebody else to do it for you?

Comment: Because I tried and what i tried didn't work.

Comment: In that case formulate a specific question with a decent description of a specific problem.

Comment: http://php.net/class.intldateformatter - http://php.net/class.intlcalendar

Comment: `Class Date{
    
    //all your functions, that look static, meaning independent
    
       static function getMonth( $monthNum ){
    
        $listMonth = array( 'janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre' );
        return $listMonth[ ( $monthNum - 1 ) ];
    
       }
    
    
    }

    Date::getMonth()`

Comment: I was about to write that answer, but it got closed :( Tidy it up and see.

Comment: Since you have tried, you should post what you tried and than we would help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has an implementation of a date formatting in OOP. Look at http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php and review how they implement it.